# setInterval doesn't work when used in a function

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I am writing a JS program to record media and output the results every few seconds. I use setInterval to call MediaRecorder.requestData() every few seconds, but this is never called.

I have add console.log debugging outputs to the interval function but they are not output, because the interval is not being called.

```
function interval() {
    mediaRecorder.requestData();
}
function stream() {
    if (navigator.mediaDevices) {
        var constraints = {audio : true, video : true};
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
        .then(function(stream) {
            mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
            mediaRecorder.start();
            mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = sendData;
        });
        interval = window.setInterval(interval, 30000);
    }
}
```

mediaRecorder is a global variable and sendData is a function that will process the blob and log it to the console.

I expect the call to interval() to occur every 30 seconds. There are no error messages in the console, but it seems that interval() is never called and that sendData() is called only when the recording is stopped manually in the browser.

Comment: Why are you setting `interval` in the `stream` function?, that can't be right.

Comment: `stream` is called when the page loads on my html page, and `interval` is a global variable

Comment: Its also the name of a function...

Comment: which one is the name of a function?

Comment: `interval` is a function

Comment: sorry I missed that, trying now

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by changing the name of the interval callback function to `intervalCallback` because of a conflict with the variable name. Thanks @Musa for advice.